# Add a new page to wordpress programmatically

Tags: pages, api

Is there a function in the wordpress api that lets me programatically add pages ?

something on the lines of :

```
add_page($title,$content)
```

Is there such a function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

Answer (score 1):

Also since WordPress integrated a HTTP API there are other new ways to handle creating content in WP via API

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/#create-a-page

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post

All very cool stuff!